# "Craven, crass and mafioso tactics"--failure of parallelism?

Tags: adjectives, parallelism, attributive-nouns

Read on the internet: "Voters rejected the craven, crass and mafioso tactics of [name withheld because this is a question about grammar, not politics]."

Sounds odd to me, because *craven* and *crass* are adjectives while *mafioso* is a noun. I would have said "the craven and crass mafioso tactics" or "the craven, crass mafioso tactics." Am I right?

Comment: It is either an attributive-noun usage or ( I don't know your source) a possible misuse of the Italian 'mafioso' where it is both a adjective and a noun.

Comment: @Josh61 I thought *mafioso* was an attributive noun, and I was wondering if attributive nouns could be used in parallel with adjectives. You will meet a tall, dark, and Harvard man? We serve hot, cold, and cabbage soup?

Comment: The author may have had no intention of using a literary technique -- it appears serious writing. Apparently, the three attributes are exactly what are relevant in the situation and what the author wanted to list. Not every sentence need be poetical or flowery speech.

Comment: "Craven" and "mafioso" make a bit of an odd couple, too, don't they? "If you don't pay the loan back by Friday at noon, I'm gonna have Mikey "the Fist" come over and whimper at you."

Comment: It sounds just fine. It doesn't sound very attributive, more like an adjective. But your example of 'tall,dark,Harvard' does have the feeling of [zeugma](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-zeugma.html)

Comment: @SvenYargs Not so sure about that. Mafiosi are—at least stereotypically—not the type to go out and do stuff themselves. They get goons to do the hard work for them and stay safe in their gambling club offices. That’s pretty craven-sounding to me, really.

Comment: I've gone with craven, crass and *crunchy*. Mafioso just doesn't go with the flow here. Maybe *cruel* would be better than crunchy; probably more on target, but I *like* crunchy.

Answer (score 0):

The failure of parallelism in the original form is minor; the syntax and semantics work ok.  Grammar does not offer good reason for your correction (aside from quibbles about using noun *mafioso* adjectively).

However, there is a failure of alliteration, or of  alliterative parallelism, given two words beginning with *cr* followed by one with *ma*.  Perhaps a third *cr* word, such as *crude* or *cruel*, could have been used in place of *mafioso* while still suggesting heavy-handed or ruthless gang-like behavior.